# How do you speed up calculating bigrams/trigrams on a large number (~ 1 million) documents in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo

I have about a million documents in mongodb with large text fields. I want to extract the most meaningful terms. My current logic has been to calculate the bigrams for each week in Python using logic similar to the logic below. The problem is this logic is slow. Is there a faster way to go about doing this?

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize

for week_start,week_end in zip(weeks[:-1],weeks[1:]):
    all_top_words = Counter()
    for post in collection.find( {'date': {'$lt': week_end, '$gte': week_start},'text':{"$exists":True}}):
        text = strip_tags(post['text'])
        text = remove_brackets(text)
        sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
        for sentence in sentences:
            sentence = sentence.lower()
            sentence = remove_punctuation(sentence)
            top_words=Counter(ngrams(sentence.split(" "),2))
            all_top_words += top_words
```

Comment: Which part of the code removes the final dot "." at the end of the sentence?

Comment: Hi. I had simplified the code for stackoverflow

Comment: Updated with something closer to my code

Comment: For speed, you could write a tokenizer which reads each character only once and splits the texts into tokens. The stream of tokens of type word is then adding to the ngram counters. Not sure if it is worth the effort, especially since treating the tags makes the tokenizer more complex.

Comment: How can one speed something up without knowing what is slow? That is, did you profile the code, or at least its inner loop?